# Deleting all elements in json array in jquery and javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I was working on a method that can erase all of the array content in "Bottin".
The data is stored on the LocalStorage of the computer in a key called "Data".

Here's my sample of Json :

```
{
    "descriptions": [
        {
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        },{
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        },{
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "Bottin": [
        {
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        }, {
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        },{
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        }
    ],
    "users": {
        "admin": "Inf2005"
    }
}
```

Here's my partial solution :

```
function delAllBottin() {
    bd = localStorage.getItem('data');      
    var descJsonObjects = bd.Bottin;
    bd.Bottin.splice(0, descJsonObjects.length);    
}
```

Doesn't seem to work for now, i don't know what i'm missing here ...

Comment: I think after delete, you should save the updated data again in localStorage.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? It shows error or just not removing the items?

Comment: @NeerajVerma : Good point ! Let me test this tomorrow morning. Will keep you posted. Guess i was too much tired.

Comment: @TareqMahmood : No error, its just not removing nothing.

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Comment: Hi Chintan, i sure did ! Was a nice simple solution. Sometime we tend to do to much when we just need to do something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, store json object in string format like:

```
var data = {
    "descriptions": [
        {
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        },{
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        },{
            "Fabricant": "Test",
            "Produit": "Test",
            "Prix": "11.11",
            "Details": " asdfasd",
            "Categorie": "Categorie_Baseball",
            "Images": "Hockey_Article_01.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "Bottin": [
        {
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        }, {
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        },{
            "Nom": "Andy",
            "Prenom": "Matador",
            "Fonction": "dtesasd",
            "Courriel": "cyd@vde.ca",
            "Telephone": "515-555-5555"
        }
    ],
    "users": {
        "admin": "Inf2005"
    }
}

localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now, to clear `Bottin` array from it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
data.Bottin = []; // array cleared
```

Now, save it again:

```
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Simple solution ! 
Gona save some CPU usage without using the for() !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1 Parse the string in localStorage to JSON

2 Remove the item you don't want (with slice() )

3 Make the JSON to string

4 Re-set it in the localStorage

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")); // updated
   for (var i =0; i< items.length; i++) {
        var items = JSON.parse(items[i]);

            items.splice(i, 1);

    }
    item = JSON.stringify(items);
    localStorage.setItem("data", items);
```

Comment: I don't think this is OP's issue. Its probably something to do with persistence of his object in local storage

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get / set an object as value for `localStorage` / `sessionStorage`. You need to make it a JSON string before setting and parse the JSON after getting from storage.

**When setting**

```
var data = {.....}; //Build your data object
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

**When getting (and editing)**

```
var jsonData = localStorage.getItem('data');
var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
//If you want to do any modification, do it now
//then set it back to the storage
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```